# Android SQLite Query Not Working

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to search data on database based on 2 conditions (entryId=rowId & category=cat_id) like below

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "favorite", new String[] {"_id", "entry"}, "entryId="+ rowId + "& category="+cat_id, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Its not working. But when I try to do it using only one condition like below then it works well.

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "favorite", new String[] {"_id", "entry"}, "entryId="+ rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Can you help me telling how can I run this query with multiple conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQLite `&` is different from `AND`, simply use:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "favorite", new String[] {"_id", "entry"}, 
        "entryId="+ rowId + " AND category="+cat_id, null, null, null, null, null);
// Change & to AND...  here:  ^^^
```